# Mutually excluding checkboxes in Word table

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I created a Word Document (Word 2016) that, by clicking a button, generates a Table with predefined text and formatting.

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| QUESTION (Y/N) | YES_Checkbox | No_Checkbox |

Row number 8 (shown above) contains a YES/NO question; to manage that, I inserted two Checkboxes (one in Column2, the other in Column3) using the following syntax:

```
For ii = 2 To 3
    Set rng = mytable.Cell(8, ii).Range
        rng.Select
    With Selection
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        .Range.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlCheckBox
        .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    End With
Next ii
```

My idea is to have mutually exclusive checkboxes: that means, if User selects "YES" the "NO" is automatically deselected (and vice-versa). To do so, I created a Sub within the main button script. It checks for the checkbox value and then tries to 'tick it' (on un-tick it) using the following code (not yet completed):

```
Sub Check_YES_Not(tblNew)
Dim thisCell As Range
check1 = mytable.Cell(8, 2).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked
check2 = mytable.Cell(8, 3).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked
    'If condition to be added
    check1 = True 'This is how I am trying to modify the checkbox, but it is not working
    'ElseIf add other conditions...
    'Msgbox "to be completed..."
    'End If
End Sub
```

Code runs and creates the table correctly, but the checkbox scripts is not behaving as I wish. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I could make it work? Thank you very much.

**UPDATE**

This is how I solved it. There are still minor concerns (e.g. if I click "Yes", I need to select another cell before clicking "No", otherwise the control is not able to work correctly). Apart from this, many thanks to @macropod and Timothy for their kind support.

In order to allow the User to create additional table, I created a `Public` counter that is increased at each added table. It is not an elegant solution, but it works for now. The initial table has a different tag (I did not include it here).

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal oCC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim collCCs As ContentControls
Dim oCCTarget As ContentControl
Dim ii As Integer
For ii = 1 To 500 'Additional tables
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("NO" + Str(ii))) Then
        Select Case oCC.Tag
          Case "YES" + Str(ii)
            Set collCCs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("NO" + Str(ii))
                For Each oCCTarget In collCCs
                  If oCCTarget.Checked = True Then
                  oCCTarget.Checked = False
                  Exit For
                  End If
                Next
          Case "NO" + Str(ii)
            Set collCCs = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("YES" + Str(ii))
                For Each oCCTarget In collCCs
                  If oCCTarget.Checked = True Then
                  oCCTarget.Checked = False
                    Exit For
                  End If
                Next
        End Select
    End If
Next ii
```

Comment: It would much simpler if you just used a dropdown with Yes & No choices. No code required to ensure only one option can be chosen. Moreover, with a dropdown you can check whether a choice has actually been made, rather than relying on inferences from the document's default state. If you're wedded to checkboxes, see, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-tables/12335-assigning-values-content-control-checkboxes-calculating-results.html#post33489 & 
https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-tables/33248-content-control-checkbox-calculations.html#post107008

Comment: Or use a single checkbox where checked means "Yes" and unchecked means "No" - that's the basic idea of a checkbox.

Comment: @FunThomas - unchecked means both "No" and "Unanswered" - that's the basic flaw of a checkbox.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: True, if you need to distinguish, you need a three-state box - no clue if this is possible in Word. On the other hand, I hate Dropdowns for a simple Yes/No selection, they are so user-unfriendly.

Comment: @FunThomas - that isn't an option in Word. Whilst I agree that a dropdown isn't quite as user friendly it does at least provide a clear indication of which questions haven't been answered.

Comment: @macropod I agree with you. I had initially wrote it using a dropdown menu, which also looks nicer to my eyes. I am trying to accommodate a request from the User to see if the checkbox option is feasible. What I had in mind is some sort of "radio button" but with the checkbox format

Comment: So did you check out the links I provided?

Comment: @macropod Indeed yes and I thank you a lot for your support. I am slowly getting there. Now my code works with only one table. I got a new requirement from the user to add another table. This ruined my solution. My way of solving this was to introduce a Public counter and then inserting into the `ContentControlOnExit` a For cycle that checks every possible counter value until 1000 (taking into account user deleting and adding multiple tables). I guess there are more elegant solutions out there, but this one currently works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't working as you are only setting the value of a variable, not the checked status of the checkbox. The simplest way of achieving your desired result is to set the checked status of one checkbox to the opposite of the other, like this:

```
mytable.Cell(8, 2).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked = Not mytable.Cell(8, 3).Range.ContentControls(1).Checked
```

Also your code to insert the content controls can be simplified to:

```
   For ii = 2 To 3
      mytable.Cell(8, ii).Range.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlCheckBox
   Next ii
```

There is rarely any need to select anything when working with Word.

Finally, you appear not to be forcing variable declaration. This can lead to avoidable errors in your code. Just add `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module. This will prevent your code from compiling when you have undeclared variables. To add this automatically to new modules open the VBE and go to Tools | Options. In the Options dialog ensure that "Require Variable Declaration" is checked.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the kind reply and for your suggestions. I have tried to insert your code into my check, but the feature only works once. Is there any way to make it permanent? i.e. User select "YES" -> "NO" is automatically deselected. After, user changes his/her mind and selects "NO" -> "YES" is automatically deselected this time.

Comment: I should mention that all started because I could not transform the icons of the Option Buttons I created (through InlineShapes.AddOLEControl) from circles with dot inside into check boxes

Comment: @hono - I don't understand what you mean about making it permanent. You need to allow the user to change their mind about an answer. If you want the code to run more than once you need to look at using the `ContentControlOnExit` event, though you will need to find a way of identifying which control has triggered the event. The usual method is to use unique tags.

Comment: I mean the same behavior as per the ActiveX "option button". I initially inserted the selection as this option button, but I was requested to change that round icon into a checkbox one, so I tried another approach (as above, which did not work).

Comment: @hono - you need to use the `ContentControlOnExit` event.